# Flow to send email to a custom object's email field

Tags: visual-workflow, email-template

I'm trying to build a flow that sends an email (from a template) to an email field within a **custom object**.

The custom object is `PDT__c`
The custom object's email field is `Email__c`

I have an email template and its related email alert (which points to `PDT__c` object).

I also have the activated flow that starts when `PDT__c.Status__c` (picklist) = "Enabled". When it happens, the flow "Sends email alert" to `{!Record.Id}`

But it doesn't.

Can anyone help me deal with this?

Thanks in advance.
Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. I had to correct the "deliverability" to "All email" in the Sandbox I was working in.

Solved.